# is it possible to classify time series-based data using statistical models like AR, MA and ARMA?

Tags: r, time-series, classification, autoregressive-models

I am trying to classify a multivariate time series data and I have used machine learning algorithms like SVM, Neural Network, KNN based on DTW, etc. Now I am going to use the statistical model like Auto Regressive to classify my data and in order to do that I have written some code in R, But it seems that classification is not possible since the result is some float numbers, not categorical numbers. have you any experience in this case? 
here is my code:

```
## status is the label of my data which is 0: Not exercising 1: 
#exercising
```

[dataset sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=166831QmSccBmuRhVJtYgG4TLdVz9N0OT)

```
library(vars)

dt=read.csv('data.csv')

# plot.ts(diff(dt$gx))
# plot.ts(dt$my)
# Box.test(dt$yaw,lag = 20,type = 'Ljung-Box')

attach(dt)

var=cbind(ax,ay,az,status)

#VARselect(var, lag.max = 10, type = "both")

model=VAR(var,type = 'const',lag.max = 10,ic = 'AIC',p = 4)
arch.test(model, lags.multi = 10)
# grangertest(status ~ ax, order = 4)

prd=predict(model, n.ahead = 10, ci = 0.95, dumvar = NULL)
```

the result of status:

$status

```
          fcst        lower      upper      CI
  [1,] 0.002911329 -0.1104069 0.1162295 0.1133182
  [2,] 0.005366295 -0.1551971 0.1659297 0.1605634
  [3,] 0.008643568 -0.1880706 0.2053577 0.1967141
  [4,] 0.009482430 -0.2172989 0.2362637 0.2267813
  [5,] 0.012580248 -0.2405501 0.2657106 0.2531303
  [6,] 0.014794586 -0.2618808 0.2914700 0.2766754
  [7,] 0.015800219 -0.2825497 0.3141501 0.2983499
  [8,] 0.015899414 -0.3023957 0.3341945 0.3182951
  [9,] 0.016415702 -0.3200783 0.3529097 0.3364940
  [10,] 0.017935262 -0.3354627 0.3713333 0.3533980
```

However, I expected 0 or 1 for it.

Comment: could you add some data to your post? no-one but you has access to `dt` and that makes it very hard to help and reproduce you problem.

Comment: @Nate Thank you for answering. I have added a sample of my dataset.

Comment: are you trying to predict the value of `status` based on the values of `ax`, `ay`, and `az`?

Comment: @ErikKornet Actually I tried to classify dataset which status is the label for each observation. So, I need to predict that status will be zero or one.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get categorial values `0` or `1` because `VAR` is not designed to be used for supervised problems (i.e. when your dataset contains labels like `status` as in your case) but for time series problems. In fact, `VAR` is constructed based on many linear regression models `lm` but used in a fancy way (I can tell you this because I managed to implement `VAR` on Spark by following the implementation in `R`).

So when you set `var=cbind(ax,ay,az,status)`you're telling `VAR` that `status` is a continuous variable, that's why you get double as output. What you're doing is a bit similar to trying to use linear regression to predict `status` and expecting the output to be always `0` or `1` when the output is always continuous, not categorical. You'd rather use logistic regression in that situation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used several classifiers including logistic regression, but I would like to test that using statistical models like ARMA can we classify our datasets which seems that we can't use them.